# запрос данных из БД

Tags: php, sql

Нужно вывести данные из таблицы "инженеры" БД test и нашла вот такой код:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1111") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM инженеры";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

  echo $row['№ п'] . "<br />";

  }

mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Поняла только половину,а остальное нет.Можно ли считать этот код применяемым в моем случае?Если нет,подскажите,пожалуйста,какой тогда будет верным.

Comment: До PHP7 ваш код, наверное, будет работать. Но я бы не стал его использовать вообще нигде.

Comment: если Вам не понятен код, то наверно не стоит его использовать, а вдруг там будут *злонамеренные* действия...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev,у меня PHP5 и он все равно не работает.

Comment: @аноним, значит вам не повезло.

Comment: в текущей Вашей постановке вопроса, ответа Вы скорее всего не дождетесь по следующим причинам: *Поняла только половину,а остальное нет.* - следует разобраться хотя бы минимально, что бы иметь минимальное представление как это работает.; *у меня PHP5 и он все равно не работает* - `exception` в студию. а так на Ваш ответ таков: **Да, код приведенный Вами может быть применяем**

Answer (score 1):

```
// Подключение к базе: где $hostname - сервер, $username - имя юзера БД,
// $password - пароль юзера, $basename - имя базы с которой мы будем работать
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$passwordname = '1111';
$basename = 'test';
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwordname, $basename) or die       ('Невозможно открыть базу');
// Формируем запрос из таблицы с именем 'инженеры'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `инженеры`";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
// В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // Оператором echo выводим на экран поля таблицы 'id' и 'name'
    echo 'Номер: '.$row['id'];
    echo 'Имя: '.$row['name'];
}
```